# How does sklearn select threshold steps in precision recall curve?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision, precision-recall

I trained a basic FFNN on a example breast cancer dataset. For the results the `precision_recall_curve` function gives datapoints for 416 different thresholds. My Data contains 569 unique prediction values, as far as I understand the Precision Recall Curve I could apply 568 different threshold values and check the resulting Precision and Recall.

But how do I do so? is there a way to set the number of thresholds to test with `sklearn`? Or at least an explanation of how `sklearn` selects those thresholds?

I mean 417 should be enough, even for bigger data sets, I am just curious how they got selected.

```
# necessary packages
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout

# load data
sk_data = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=False)

# safe data in pandas
data = sk_data['data']
target = sk_data['target']
target_names = sk_data['target_names']
feature_names = sk_data['feature_names']
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=feature_names)

# build ANN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', input_dim=30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(32, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# train ANN
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(data, target, epochs=50, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.2)

# eval
pred = model.predict(data)

# calculate precision-recall curve
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(target, pred)

# precision-recall curve and f1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#pyplot.plot([0, 1], [0.5, 0.5], linestyle='--')
plt.plot(recall, precision, marker='.')
# show the plot
plt.show()

len(np.unique(pred)) #569
len(thresholds) # 417
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reading the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py#L530), `precision_recall_curve` does compute precision and recall for each unique predicted probability (here `pred`) but then omits the output for all thresholds that result in full recall (apart from the very first threshold to achieve full recall).