# Confidence thresholds on mean average precision calculation

Tags: scikit-learn

is there any rules for PR curve threshold because in sklearn.metrics.average_precision they automatically make threshold from the prob/confidence which can result in weird result if I have inputs like this:

```
y_true = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
y_scores = np.array([ 0.7088982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

it will output mAP = 0.93333. Sklearn implementation got that number because it automatically uses [0.7088982, 0] as the thresholds. When the prob threshold is 0 all of zero score will counted as positive resulting in high map. Is this a correct behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of considerations on your example:

- the peculiarity of your `y_scores`, having two distinct values only, defines the length of your `threshold`. As you might see from [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L766) and as
  you may logically imply, `threshold` is defined by the number of distinct values in `y_scores`.
- then, your argument is correct and implicit in what the `threshold` represents. Actually, if the score is greater or equal than the `threshold`,
  the instance is assigned to the positive class. Therefore, in the case score=threshold=0 you'll have true positives only based on your `y_true` (and in turn the average precision is a weighted mean of precisions achieved at each threshold).
  Have a look also [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L820) to observe that

> Precision values such that element i is the precision of predictions with *score >= thresholds[i]*

and

> Decreasing recall values such that element i is the recall of predictions with *score >= thresholds[i]*

I'd also suggest you to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865028/sklearn-precision-recall-curve-and-threshold/64838319#64838319) to get a glimpse of how `precision`, `recall` and `threshold` are computed within `precision_recall_curve()`.

Comment: To give more context, I was tinkering with some old faster r-cnn repo on Github (https://github.com/you359/Keras-FasterRCNN). They use sklearn average precision implementation to compute mAP score. I was getting pretty good score when the model actually perform really bad. It fails to detect most object. Turns out the repo makes false negative detection as positive detection with 0 confidence to match sklearn AP function input. I ended up writing different implementation bcz this implementation doesn't know how many ground truth are in the image.

Comment: Also, I already understand what you have explained.  I come out with this question bcz i've seen other implementations manually generate their own threshold starting from above 0 so 0 confidence scores always count as negative.