# Why does precision_recall_curve() return different values than confusion matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix, precision-recall

I have written the following code to calculate the precision and the recall for a multiclass classification problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return idx

# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y.shape[1]

# Add noisy features to make the problem harder
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# shuffle and split training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Learn to predict each class against the other
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(
    svm.SVC(kernel="linear", probability=True, random_state=random_state)
)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_score = classifier.decision_function(X_test)

# Confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_test_pred =  classifier.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred))

# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
precision = dict()
recall = dict()
threshold = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    c = classifier.classes_[i]
    precision[c], recall[c], threshold[c] = precision_recall_curve(y_test[:, c], y_score[:, c])
    th0 = find_nearest(threshold[c], 0)
    print(c, round(precision[c][th0],2), round(recall[c][th0], 2))
```

What I am trying to do is to re-calculate the precision and the recall shown by the confusion matrix

```
precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.73      0.52      0.61        21
           1       1.00      0.07      0.12        30
           2       0.57      0.33      0.42        24

   micro avg       0.68      0.28      0.40        75
   macro avg       0.77      0.31      0.39        75
weighted avg       0.79      0.28      0.36        75
 samples avg       0.28      0.28      0.28        75
```

by using the `precision_recall_curve()` function. In theory it should return the exact same results as the confusion matrix when the threshold is equals to 0.
However my results do not match the final result:

```
  precsion recall
0     0.75   0.57
1      1.0    0.1
2      0.6   0.38
```

Would you be able to explain this difference and how to properly calculate the values of the confusion matrix report?

Comment: Actually, considering index `th0 + 1` rather than `th0` will solve the problem - in your case. If you have a look at the corresponding thresholds, you'll see that the values of precisions and recalls that you'll find in `classification_report` are those whose thresholds are not only closer to 0, but also *positive*. For a more consistent approach, you'll need to adjust `find_nearest` accordingly. However, the underlying reason is not straightforward for me at the moment :P. Hope to be able to elaborate more later

Comment: Ok perfect thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote within the comment, considering index `th0 + 1` rather than index `th0` will solve the problem in your case. However, that might be just a case (as in this specific example the thresholds which are closer to 0 do always correspond to negative scores); therefore, for a programmatic approach, imo you should modify `find_nearest` to return the index for which `threshold` is positive and closest to 0. Indeed, you can see that by adding

```
print(th0, threshold[c][th0-1], threshold[c][th0], threshold[c][th0+1])
```

you'll get the following output:

```
20 -0.011161920989200713 -0.01053513227868108 0.016453546101096173
67 -0.04226738229343663 -0.0074193008862454835 0.09194626401603534
38 -0.011860865951094923 -0.003756310149749531 0.0076752136658660985
```

For a more programmatic approach, you can naively modify `find_nearest` as follows and keep index `th0` within your loop.

```
def find_nearest_new(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(np.where(array > 0, array, 999) - value)).argmin()
    return idx
...
for i in range(n_classes):
    c = classifier.classes_[i]
    precision[c], recall[c], threshold[c] = precision_recall_curve(y_test[:, c], y_score[:, c])
    th0 = find_nearest_new(threshold[c], 0)
    print(c, round(precision[c][th0],6), round(recall[c][th0], 6), round(threshold[c][th0],6))
```

My clue is the following, namely the fact that within `precision_recall_curve` implementation precision and recall are defined as follows:

> precision: ndarray of shape (n_thresholds + 1,)
> Precision values such that *element i is the precision of predictions with* ***score >= thresholds[i]*** and the last element is 1.

> recall: ndarray of shape (n_thresholds + 1,)
> Decreasing recall values such that *element i is the recall of predictions* with ***score >= thresholds[i]*** and the last element is 0.

In other terms, if you sort the scores in descending order (according to the implementation) you'll see that the selected thresholds (whether you consider index `th0 + 1`) coincide with the first positive scores per class (indeed thresholds are nothing else but the distinct score values). On the other hand, if you stick to index `th0` (in this specific example) you'll get scores which are strictly less than threshold=0.

```
for i in range(n_classes):
    c = classifier.classes_[i]
    precision[c], recall[c], threshold[c] = precision_recall_curve(y_test[:, c], y_score[:, c])
    th0 = find_nearest(threshold[c], 0)
    print(c, round(precision[c][th0+1],6), round(recall[c][th0+1], 6), round(threshold[c][th0+1],6))
    #print(c, precision[c], recall[c], threshold[c])
    print(np.sort(y_score[:,c])[::-1])
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865028/sklearn-precision-recall-curve-and-threshold/64838319#64838319) might be of help to get a grasp of how things work within `precision_recall_curve()`.