# How to get the threshold from a specific precision and recall

Tags: scikit-learn, precision, threshold

I'm trying to get the threshold for a specific precision and recall. Let's say I want to get the threshold at the precision of 60% and recall of 40%. Are there any straightforward way to do it using the sklearn package?

```
precision, recall, threshold = precision_recall_curve(y_val, y_e)
df_pr = pd.DataFrame()
df_pr['precision'] = precision
df_pr['recall'] = recall
df_pr['threshold'] = list(threshold) + [1]

    precision   recall  threshold
0   0.247543    1.000000    0.059483
1   0.247486    0.999692    0.059489
2   0.247504    0.999692    0.059512
3   0.247523    0.999692    0.059542
```

Comment: The `df_pr` you show looks kinda strange.  Why isn't the last `threshold` = 1?

Comment: Imo your precision and recall won't be necessarily coupled as you seem to imply. This said, you can determine the index for which you attain either - I would say - your expected precision value or your expected recall value and consequently get the corresponding threshold value.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that I've properly understood your question, imo, the point to highlight is that precision and recall are not necessarily coupled as you seem to imply. Here's a toy example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=7)
lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=42)
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_scores = lr.predict_proba(X_test)
precision, recall, threshold = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_scores[:, 1])

plt.plot(threshold, precision[:-1], 'b--', label='Precision')
plt.plot(threshold, recall[:-1], 'r--', label='Recall')
plt.xlabel('Threshold')
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.ylim([0,1])
```

[image]

This said, the problem becomes something you can easily solve either with *numpy* or *pandas*, depending on your "setting". For instance, here's a toy function returning precision, recall and threshold at the index where the condition is attained.

```
def prt(arr, value):
    array = np.asarray(arr)
    idx = np.where(array[:-1] == value)[0][0]
    return precision[idx], recall[idx], threshold[idx]

prt(precision, 0.6)   # I checked ex-ante that precision=0.6 is attained. Differently you'll have to go with something custom.
(0.6, 0.9622641509433962, 0.052229434776723364)
```

Otherwise, to resemble your setting with a pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['precision'] = precision[:-1]
df['recall'] = recall[:-1]
df['threshold'] = threshold
df[df.loc[:, 'precision'] == 0.6]
```

[image]

I would suggest you [sklearn precision_recall_curve and threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865028/sklearn-precision-recall-curve-and-threshold/64838319#64838319) that tries to explain how `.precision_recall_curve()` works under the hood and [Why does precision_recall_curve() return different values than confusion matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70567206/why-does-precision-recall-curve-return-different-values-than-confusion-matrix/70568589#70568589) which might be somehow related.

Comment: Because of floating point precision there might not be exact match. It is better to use
`idx = np.where(array[:-1] >= value)[0][0]` instead