# sklearn's precision_recall_curve incorrect on small example

Tags: scikit-learn, precision-recall

Here is a very small example using precision_recall_curve():

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, precision_score, recall_score
y_true = [0, 1]
y_predict_proba = [0.25,0.75]
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_predict_proba)
precision, recall
```

which results in:

```
(array([1., 1.]), array([1., 0.]))
```

The above does not match the "manual" calculation which follows.

There are three possible class vectors depending on threshold: [0,0] (when the threshold is > 0.75) , [0,1] (when the threshold is between 0.25 and 0.75), and [1,1] (when the threshold is <0.25).  We have to discard [0,0] because it gives an undefined precision (divide by zero).  So, applying precision_score() and recall_score() to the other two:

```
y_predict_class=[0,1]
precision_score(y_true, y_predict_class), recall_score(y_true, y_predict_class)
```

which gives:

```
(1.0, 1.0)
```

and

```
y_predict_class=[1,1]
precision_score(y_true, y_predict_class), recall_score(y_true, y_predict_class)
```

which gives

```
(0.5, 1.0)
```

This seems not to match the output of precision_recall_curve() (which for example did not produce a 0.5 precision value).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but I had your same doubt that I have eventually solved.
The main point here is that `precision_recall_curve()` does not output precision and recall values anymore after full recall is obtained the first time; moreover, it concatenates a 0 to the `recall` array and a 1 to the `precision` array so as to let the curve start in correspondence of the y-axis.

In your specific example, you'll have effectively two arrays done like this (they are ordered the other way around because of the specific implementation of `sklearn`):

```
precision, recall
(array([1., 0.5]), array([1., 1.]))
```

Then, the values of the two arrays which do correspond to the second occurrence of full recall are omitted and 1 and 0 values (for precision and recall, respectively) are concatenated as described above:

```
precision, recall
(array([1., 1.]), array([1., 0.]))
```

I have tried to explain it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865028/sklearn-precision-recall-curve-and-threshold/64838319#64838319) in full details; another useful link is certainly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076966/how-does-sklearn-select-threshold-steps-in-precision-recall-curve).