# sklearn's roc_curve() function returns thresholds and fpr of different dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I assume that `roc_curve()` computes fpr and tpr for each value of thresholds.
But the following code shows that fpr and thresholds have different dimensions.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
fpr,tpr,thresholds = roc_curve(y_train_5,y_scores)
```

```
fpr.shape #(3908,)
thresholds.shape #(59966,)
```

I am also wondering why

```
precisions,recalls,thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_train_5,y_scores)
precisions #(59967,)
thresholds #(59966,)
```

precisions's dimension differs from thresholds' by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what concerns `roc_curve()`, differently than for precision/recall curves, the lengths of the outputs do depend on `drop_intermediate` option (default to True), meant for dropping suboptimal thresholds (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) for reference).

For the second point, the threshold is not outputted anymore whenever full recall is achieved. This might be the reason; [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865028/sklearn-precision-recall-curve-and-threshold/64838319#64838319) or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061695/sklearns-precision-recall-curve-incorrect-on-small-example/64843979#64843979) might help, too.